# push notification badge does not reset when app opened - Trigger IO

Tags: parse-platform, trigger.io

iOS badge does not clear via Parse REST Push notification API if called when app is opened, and if we call API on app paused event provided by trigger io it still doesn't get clear as code doesn't get executed in app paused event until again app is resumed. note mention in this question not working https://www.parse.com/questions/push-notification-badge-not-resetting-via-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the badge with the Forge Notification module:

```
forge.notification.setBadgeNumber(number, success, error)
```

See https://trigger.io/modules/notification/current/docs/index.html#forgenotificationsetbadgenumbernumber-success-error